# ¿Cómo validar si selecciono un checkbox o se ingresó cantidad en un campo de texto, jquery?

Tags: jquery

Buen día.

Recientemente tengo una función, donde obtengo el valor de la fila ya sea por checkbox o por el valor que se ingresó en el cuadro de texto:

La tabla visualmente es de esta forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con esta función obtengo los datos ya sean del checkbox o del campo "cantidad",

```
$('.formas_pagos').on('change', '.tipo_pago, .cantidad', function(e) {
    let monto_ingresado = tipo_pago.find('.cantidad').val();
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        console.log("Checkbox chequeado");
    } else {
        console.log("Checkbox deseleccionado");
    }

    if (monto_ingresado) {
        console.log("se ingreso valor en el campo de texto");
    } else {
        console.log("Borro el valor del input");
    }
});
```

Ambas validaciones las quiero manejar por aparte, si utilizo checkbox o campo de texto, el detalle que tengo es que cuando utilizo un checkbox, me ejecuta  el `else` donde se encuentra `console.log("Borro el valor del input");` y si deselecciono el checkbox tambien me envía al `else` donde se encuentra `console.log("Borro el valor del input");`

Comment: En la variable monto_ingresado que tienes almacenado?

Comment: el valor que ingrese en el cuadro de texto "cantidad"

Comment: Podrías explicar mas cual es el objetivo final? Yo personalmente no entendí lo que necesitas. Saludos

Comment: debo controlar ciertas validaciones si se utiliza el checkbox o ingresa manual mente una cantidad en la variable "monto_ingresado".

Comment: Tiene que ser uno u otro pero no ambos? Por ejemplo, tener seleccionado el checkbox y tener llenado el campo al mismo tiempo, a eso nos referimos con que no se entiende bien tu problemática.

Comment: exacto, uno o otro.

Comment: Entonces cuando selecciones el checkbox, se debe de borrar el texto del input y cuando llenes el input se debe de deseleccionar el checkbox?

Comment: asi es. Eso me faltara añadirlo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En base a lo que entendí sobre tu problema, esta es una posible solución, ejemplo:

```
<div class="formas_pagos">
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" class="tipo_pago" />
<input type="text" id="text" class="cantidad" />
</div>
```

Tengo el input y el checkbox dentro de un div que tiene sus respectivas clases para poder usar tus funciones.

```
let monto_ingresado = $('.cantidad').val();
$('.formas_pagos').on('change', '.tipo_pago', function(e) {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        console.log("Checkbox chequeado");
        monto_ingresado = $('.cantidad').val("");
    } else {
        console.log("Checkbox deseleccionado");
    }
});

$('.formas_pagos').on('input', '.cantidad', function(e) {
    if (monto_ingresado != "") {
        console.log("se ingreso valor en el campo de texto");
        $(".tipo_pago").prop('checked', false);
    } else {
        console.log("Borro el valor del input");
    }
});
```

Tienes que hacer funciones por separado, por que el input detecta cuando escribes y quita el check, y el checkbox reacciona al evento change, si le dejas el evento change al input solo se accionara cuando des click fuera de el(probado) es por eso que es mejor el evento "input".

Practicamente lo que hace el ejemplo: Si el checkbox esta seleccionado y quieres escribir en el input, el checkbox quita su check, pero si tienes texto en el input y das check, el texto es borrado.

[Ejemplo funcional](https://jsfiddle.net/vm7j9acn/)

Comment: en el editor de texto para responder tienes una opción que es "código javascript...." Con esa formato le das la opción de probarlo aquí nomas sin mandarlo a otra pagina. Aparte de que es mas fácil de redactar. Saludos!

Comment: No estaba enterado de eso compañero, muchas gracias por el consejo. Saludos!.